# How to classify edge-images which belong to two highly changeable but distinguishable classes according to edges (contours) "curviness"

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, classification, edges

**Introduction**

I am working on a project in OpenCV in C++ and I am trying to classify a small image (a frame from a video) containing many edges into two groups. I would also like to retain the information of how close the image is to class A or to class B, because this classification does not seem to be simply a binary problem - sometimes the images is a mixture of class A and B.

Class A can be roughly determined by existence of curvy/smooth edges, similar to arches or parts of elliptic structures, which often are oriented into some kind of center (like in a tunnel).

The other class, class B is usually very chaotic and the edges on such image are definitely less curvy, they are often winding and usually don't have any kind of "center of attention".

**Classes**:

The images from both classes are in following links:
[Group A](http://i.imgsafe.org/1468e4b.png)
[Group B](http://i.imgsafe.org/15ac094.png)

**Previous approaches and ideas**

I was trying to separate each sufficiently long contour and then calculate some kind of curvature/curviness coefficient - basically I downsampled the contour (by 10), then I traversed along the new contour and calculated the average value of absolute angle between two segments created by 3 consecutive points. Then based on this value I determined whether a current contour is "curvy" or not. According to that I calculated a few features:

- total length of curvy contours / total length of all contours
- number of curvy contours / number of all contours
- etc.

However, the very curvature calculation seems to be not working very robustly (in one frame a contour is considered to be curvy, in second the same contour with slighly changed shape is not etc.) and also setting the threshold to determine which contour is curvy and which is not (based on "avereage curvines of single contour") is difficult to set properly. Also, such approach in no way takes into account the specific "shape" of class A and therefore classification results are very poor.

I was thinking about some kind of ellipse fitting, but as you can see, the class A is more like a group of arches than actual ellipse or circle.

I was reading about some ways of comparing edge maps such as Hausdorff matching, but it does not seem to be very helpful in my case. Also, it is important, that I want to keep the algorithm simple, because it has to be able to work in real time and also it is only a part of bigger software.

**Finally, my question is:**

Do you have any ideas of any other, better features and calculations that I can use to describe and then classify such edges/images? Is there a robust solution to describe my classes?

Comment: Could you post sample images for classes A and B?

Comment: I am not sure if I can show the original frames, because the edge frames I posted are based on medical videos taken during procedures on real hospital patients. That is why I only posted the frames after some preprocessing: http://i.imgsafe.org/1468e4b.png and http://i.imgsafe.org/15ac094.png

Comment: Maybe you could pass every contour to isContourConvex  and count how many contours are convex. It's just an idea, dont know if this helps.
(http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=iscontour#bool%20isContourConvex%28InputArray%20contour%29)

Comment: Thanks for idea, but after implementation it did not prove to be successful.  Almost none of the contours in multiple samples were detected as convex.

Comment: I think that the issue relies partly on findContours() function which seems to work pretty unpredictably. Namely, even in case of simple segments edges OpenCV does not retrieve the contours correctly. Instead it gives us some kind of a bounding contour around the original edge. Because of that even starting/ending point in vector<cv::Points> is never actually in actual edge start/end. To clarify I am attaching the link to illustration of this problem: http://i.imgsafe.org/7a5dd78.png

Comment: Have you tried to compute the 'structure tensor' on those images? Class A really look somewhat like concentric arcs around the image center. The orientation part of a structure tensor calculated with a large scale might reproduce this concentric strucure. The class B looks more like a somewhat parallel orientation of all line segments. This should be reflected by the structure tensor. Then, a histogram or maybe the entropy of the orientation values will discriminate both classes.

Comment: I did not try but I will give it a try in Matlab first. It sounds like an interesting idea, thanks!